# What do I need to look for in this syntax error?

Tags: sqlite

**[strong text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Xbcn.png)**

** I have been using the Chinook Database with SQLite to learn some SQL. The goal is to create a list of album titles and the unit prices for the artist "Audioslave". The "strong text" link will show the Chinook Database that I have been using to run this query.**

I have attempted to run this query using the concept of subqueries and I keep getting an error saying: near "SELECT": syntax error.

Here is the code that I have so far.

```
SELECT UnitPrice
FROM tracks
Where AlbumID IN 
    SELECT AlbumID
    FROM Albums
    Where AlbumID IN (SELECT Name
        FROM artists
            Where Name = 'Audioslave');
```

Any response would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing () after IN

```
SELECT UnitPrice
FROM tracks
Where AlbumID IN 
( SELECT AlbumID
    FROM Albums
    Where AlbumID IN (SELECT Name
        FROM artists
            Where Name = 'Audioslave'));
```